# Clean up XML using netbeans

Tags: xml, netbeans

Is it possible to clean up XML using only Netbeans IDE? For example the indentation is not as it supposed to be.

Comment: do you mean Indentation instead of Identation? If so I don't think Netbeans will auto adjust this particular problem.

Comment: @VoodoChild sorry it was a little typo. But alt+shift+f will clean up your code :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I already found the answer to my question.

```
alt+shift+f
```

or go to menu

```
source -> format
```

Comment: Works fine for selected block of text only